# how to make "enter" summit a textarea

Tags: javascript, key, enter

I need to know how to send a message in my textarea using enter, not only with the submit button.

This is my code.

```
 function onSend () {
  const textareaValue = $textarea.value;

  if (textareaValue !== '') {
    const template = `<div class="conversation-active">
    <img src="Foto1.png" alt="Avatar">
    <div class="box-message">
    <p class="name">Michael Alean</p>
    <span class="time-message">${timeNow}</span>
    <div class="message">
    <p>${textareaValue}</p>
    </div>        
    </div>`;
    $chat.innerHTML += template;
    $textarea.value = '';
  } 
}
```

Comment: You will need to attach an event listener to the textarea for the `keydown` event.  When it happens, check to see if the event is for the enter key.  If it is, cancel the event (so an enter is not inserted into the textarea), and logically submit your form.

Comment: Textareas are UI elements where the UX is to hit Enter and expect the cater in a new line. Why would you want to use a textarea at all - instead of an HTMLInputElement type text?

Answer (score 0):

you can use like this:

firstly declare named pressed function.
this function checks whether the enter key is pressed. if pressed to the enter key will be manually trigger to onSend function.

```
function pressed(e) {
        // Has the enter key been pressed?
        if ( (window.event ? event.keyCode : e.which) == 13) { 
            // If it has been so, manually trigger onSend function
            onSend();
        }
    }
```

Secondly you should add to textarea props the this code
**onkeydown="pressed(event)"**
like this:

```
<textarea name="myTextArea" onkeydown="pressed(event)"></textarea>
```

Comment: If you (hopefully) don't use inline `style=""` attributes, than please don't suggest to use inline `on*=""` attribute handlers. JS should be in one place only, and that's inside a `script` file or tag, not disseminated in an undebuggable and unmaintainable manner around your HTML.

Comment: If you are passing in the event, trying to look for the non-standard global variable seems like unnecessary complexity.

Comment: Also, we're humans, not machines, you could use `Event.key`, or for keyboard internationalization (well, perhaps not needed for the Enter key, but just to get a habit) `Event.code`

Answer (score 0):

The enter key creates linefeeds (LFs) in a textarea so I suspect you're using the wrong type of input field.

Normally, for input type=”text” or input type=”url” you can use the event...

```
onchange="alert('OK');"
```

Which does fire when you press the enter key but not in a textarea.

Forcing a textarea to fire with the enter key; although not impossible, is pretty stupid and a sign that you are using the wrong field type.